# É permitido a um compilador omitir um membro referência em uma classe?

Tags: c++, advogado-de-linguagem

Considere a seguinte classe:

```
struct Type {
    int a, b, c;
    int& ref;
    Type(int m) : a(m), b(m), c(m), ref(a) { }
    Type(const Type& ot) : a(ot.a), b(ot.b), c(ot.c), ref(a) { }
} obj;
```

Aqui temos que o `sizeof(Type)` é `24`. No entanto `obj.ref` pode **sempre e em qualquer situação/contexto** ser substituído por `obj.a`, fazendo com que a referência possa ser resolvida em tempo de compilação e tornando *inútil* guardar os 8 bytes da referência no objeto (e os 4 de padding). Idealmente o `sizeof(Type)` pode ser `12` (apenas os três `int`s).

Um compilador pode executar essa otimização enquanto que seguindo estritamente as regras do standard? Por que? Existe alguma situação em que essa otimização seria incorreta?

**Demonstre com um exemplo que produza comportamento diferente com/sem a otimização.**

Comment: Acredito que esse tipo de otimização não é permitida, pois mexe no layout da struct/classe. Mas tenho que pesquisar pra dar uma resposta com certeza.

Comment: Penso o mesmo. **Mas**, não consigo achar nenhum caso em que isso vire um problema ou uma incompatibilidade. Nota: Nenhum dos compiladores que testei fazem isso (obviamente).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, o standard afirma o seguinte na sessão 8.3.2, paragrafo 4:

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage.

Então um compilador é livre para omitir a alocação de uma referência sempre que isso não alterar o comportamento do programa. O tamanho do objeto *pode* ser `12`.

No caso da pergunta, a otimização será válida se e somente se o compilador puder **provar** que `obj.ref` sempre resulta em `obj.a`, ou seja, qualquer construção de uma referência em `obj.ref` será feita de forma que esta "aponte" para `obj.a`.

Referências recebem um objeto na sua inicialização e não podem ser mudadas até a destruição. Se uma referência é membro, então tem sua vida igual a vida do objeto que a contém, logo o único lugar onde é legal inicializar uma referência é na inicialização do objeto, isso ocorre na lista de inicialização dos construtores.

Se o compilador pode ver todos os construtores na definição da classe e se **todos** eles inicializam a referência da mesma forma (para um membro do próprio objeto), então não existe como a referência em qualquer momento referenciar outro objeto. Logo **a otimização é válida** para o exemplo da pergunta.

Comment: Entretanto os compiladores não a implementam. Ou ela não é realmente válida, ou é muito custoso fazer a checagem de sua validade para valer a pena.

Comment: Ou criar uma referência dentro da classe para um membro dela mesma é algo que ninguém são faria e eles não tem por que implementar a otimização.

Answer (score 2):

O seu caso já <s>é</s> era uma situação problemática:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Type {
    int a, b, c;
    int& ref;
    Type(int m) : a(m), b(m), c(m), ref(a) { }
};

int main() {
    Type a(42);
    Type b(a);

    std::cout << &a.ref << "  " << &b.ref << std::endl;
    std::cout << &a.a << "  " << &b.a << std::endl;
}

0xbfb1efa0  0xbfb1efa0
0xbfb1efa0  0xbfb1efb0
```

http://ideone.com/e65KKt

Como o compilador pode com inteligência suficiente se garantir que tal otimização faria com que o comportamento não mudasse (entre a implementação de referência via ponteiros ou por sua omissão) para este exemplo e outros casos possíveis?

Mais info sobre possíveis otimizações no uso de referências em: http://www.preney.ca/paul/archives/1051

Comment: Estava faltando um bom construtor de cópia. Assumindo que o compilador veja que ele existe (veja questão atualizada), o seu exemplo não é mais válido. Ainda assim, boa tentativa

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal meu argumento continuaria sendo o mesmo, foi só um exemplo baseado no seu código original. Você está requisitando que o compilador realize uma prova, para que a otimização possa então ser realizada.

Comment: E ainda há como fazer a referência apontar para outro lugar com esse meu construtor de cópia? Se não, então um compilador poderia provar a otimização válida.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal não sei, ainda não parei pra pensar, mas outra coisa também seria verificar o padrão a respeito das regras de layout/etc para membros e ver se tem algo que elimine a necessidade dessa linha de raciocínio.

Answer (score 0):

Uma subclasse de `Type` pode sobrescrever o construtor e inicializar `ref` de forma diferente. Isso invalidaria essa otimização.

Comment: sobrescrever um construtor? o que vejo possível como situação problema no caso dele é fazer uso de outros construtores implícitos, porém não é possível sobrescrever construtores base.

Comment: É verdade! Não é permitido inicializar membros de superclasses no construtor. `SubType(int m) : Type(m), ref(b) {}` não é permitido.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser: Mesmo se esses membros forem públicos, como no caso do exemplo do Guilherme?

Comment: @missingno é possível apenas a reinicialização de membros da base nos construtores derivados, ou seja, não funciona na lista de inicialização do construtor da classe derivada, somente no corpo, depois que já ocorreu a inicialização via construtor da base.

Answer (score 0):

Eu vejo problema se duas unidades de compilação diferentes (dois arquivos .cpp) usassem essa `struct` (via definição em um arquivo .h, por exemplo), e em uma delas a compilação fosse com otimização e na outra sem otimizações. Seria impossível linkar os arquivos objeto gerados pelas duas unidades depois.

Desta forma, algo assim deveria ser uma otimização proibida, ou sempre obrigatória, já que se fosse opcional (e configurável, como outras otimizações) tornaria impossível o modelo de compilação separada da linkagem que vigora na linguagem.

Comment: Como a definição estaria no `.hpp`, o compilador poderia detectar ela em todos os arquivos. Sobre a ABI, ela sempre foi não *standarlizada* e conectar arquivos compilador com compiladores diferentes, ou versões diferentes, ou mesmo flags diferentes já pode dar problema. Então a meu ver nenhum dessas questões seria realmente um impessilho.